# showing div when hover another div won't work

Tags: css, hover

I'm trying to create an area with two columns (boxes). in each column there will be several links. When hovering one link I want to show information about the link underneath.

Okay so i've got this code (for only one link that would be)

```
.area
{
width: 840px;
position:fixed; left:50%;
margin:50px 0px 20px -420px;
float:left;
text-align: center;
}

.box
{
width:400px;
text-align: center;
float:left;
margin: 0 5px 0px 5px;
line-height:24px;
}

.link
{
width:400px;
margin-bottom:5px;
background-color:#222;
color: #FFF;
font-weight:bold;
line-height:24px;
}

.linkinfo
{
display: none;
width:400px;
margin-bottom:5px;
color: #222;
line-height:24px;
}

.link:hover .linkinfo
{
display:block;
}
```

and then this:

```
<div class="area">

<div class="box">

<div class="link"><a href="URL>here goes the link</a></div>
    <div class="linkinfo">
    Here</br>
    goes</br>
    the</br>
    information</br>
    </div>

<div class="somethingelse">there's also other stuff in the box</div>

</div>

<div class="box">
this is the other column
</div>

</div>
```

The Problem however is that it won't work like this.
"linkinfo" doesn't show when I hover the "link".

**But** it does work when I change the code to this:
(.box:hover instead of .link:hover)

```
.box:hover .linkinfo
{
display:block;
}
```

But I need it to show when hovering *only* the link, not the whole box. What am I missing?

Comment: Change `.link:hover .linkinfo` to `.link:hover + .linkinfo`

Comment: Maybe something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/VQr7T/